# How to update an array of tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update a field in multiple tables based on an array of ids. I'm not quite sure how to do this, I've tried the below but that doesn't work:

```
UPDATE 'call_list_row' SET emailed='0' WHERE id=('1','2','3');
```

Comment: `where id in (...)`... `=` tests SINGLE values for equality. `in` tests for membership in a set of values.

Comment: The fact that you are even attempting this suggests that normalizing your database might be worth considering.

Comment: Multiple tables? If that is not a typo, see Dan's comment above.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean multiple tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for an array, you need to use the `IN` keyword

```
UPDATE call_list_row 
  SET emailed='0' 
  WHERE id IN ('1','2','3');
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: don't use `''` around table-names. It would be treated as a `string`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I wasn't aware that table names couldn't be enclosed in quotes